# setup bitbucket access using bearer token in spring cloud config server

Tags: spring-cloud-config

As described by [bitckets](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucketserver072/personal-access-tokens-1005335924.html#:%7E:text=To%20generate%20a%20personal%20access,the%20users%20personal%20tokens%20page.&text=Use%20permissions%20to%20get%20the%20correct%20access%20for%20different%20users), now personal access tokens are free from user. And can be used as bearer tokens to access repositories.

But I couldn't find any way to configure bearer tokens inplace of username and password in spring cloud config server.

```
spring:
    cloud:
        config:
            server: 
                git:
                    uri: https://my-bicket.com/bu/myrepo.git
                    username: my-username
                    password: my-token
```

Is it supported by spring cloud config server.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a Repository Access Token to access a repository containing your external configuration, you'll need to use 'x-token-auth' as a username. Here's an example of how this would look in your Spring Cloud configuration file:

```
spring:
  cloud:
    config:
        server: 
            git:
                uri: https://bitbucket.org/<<project>>/<<repository>>.git
                username: x-token-auth
                password: <<your_token>>
```

Remember to replace project, repository, and your_token with your own BitBucket details. In this case, <<your_token>> would be your Repository Access Token.